# libopenmpi-dbg for ubuntu 16

Tags: openmpi, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to get my environment set up for a class project on OpenMpi and following the instructions here - http://lsi.ugr.es/~jmantas/pdp/ayuda/datos/instalaciones/Install_OpenMPI_en.pdf 
I have ubuntu 16 and it gives no package found when I try to install libopenmpi-dbg.

Answer (score 0):

I installed manually the deb file downloaded from here:

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/universe/base/libopenmpi-dbg

Then i used: sudo apt-get install -f to install the dependencies. This worked for me...